# Downloading files and install from internal storage

Tags: android

I would rather my application save and install the zip file in the internal storage for the app than the users sdcard so there isn't files being created which may limit users without sdcard. Could someone direct me on how to change my code so the zip file is saved internal storage rather than sdcard.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.downloadbible);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnLanguage);
    languageList.clear();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("languageName", "");
    languageList.add(map);

    languageAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, languageList, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
        new String[] {"languageName"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    languageAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder viewBinder = new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                String textRepresentation) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.setText(textRepresentation);
            return true;
        }
    };
    languageAdapter.setViewBinder(viewBinder);
    spinner.setAdapter(languageAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            refreshBibleList(parent, position);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            //do nothing
        }
    });

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {      
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File downloadFolder = new File(sdcard.getPath() + Constants.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER);
        if (!downloadFolder.isDirectory()) {
            boolean success = downloadFolder.mkdirs();          
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating download directory success: " + success);
        }
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.confirmDownload);
    builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.yes), this);
    builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.no), this);
    confirmDownload = builder.create();

    readPreference();

    adapter = new DisplayDownloadAdapter(this, R.layout.rowdownload, bibleList, currentFontSize);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

    try {
        URL url = new URL(homeUrl + "bible_index_all.txt");
        Log.d(TAG, "Accessing Bible Repository All");
        pdRepository = ProgressDialog.show(this, 
                getResources().getString(R.string.pleaseWait), 
                getResources().getString(R.string.loading), true, false);
        new LoadingRepositoryTask().execute(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.repositoryUrlNotValid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private boolean refreshBibleList(AdapterView<?> parent, int position) {
    if (parent.getAdapter().isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Map<String, String> data = (Map<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    bibleList.clear();
    for (DisplayDownload bible : allBibleList) {
        if (bible.getLanguage() != null && bible.getLanguage().equals(data.get("languageName"))) {
            bibleList.add(bible);
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
}

private void readPreference() {
    SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    currentFontSize = preference.getInt(Constants.FONT_SIZE, 14);
}

private class LoadingRepositoryTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object> {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg) {
        languageSet.clear();
        allBibleList.clear();
        URL url = (URL) arg[0];
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            InputStream is= conn.getInputStream();
            if (is == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            int i = 0;
            if (is != null) {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                String line = null;

                byte[] bomUtf8 = new byte[] {(byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xBF};
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] arrLine = line.split(";;");
                    if (arrLine.length != 4) continue;
                    if (i == 0) { //check for UTF-8 bom
                        if (Character.toString(arrLine[0].charAt(0)).equals(new String(bomUtf8, "UTF-8"))) {
                            arrLine[0] = arrLine[0].substring(1);
                        }                           
                    }
                    i++;                        
                    allBibleList.add(new DisplayDownload(arrLine[0], arrLine[1], arrLine[2], arrLine[3]));
                    if (!languageSet.contains(arrLine[0])) {
                        languageSet.add(arrLine[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return String.valueOf(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error reading bible_index", e);
            return ERROR + Util.getRootCause(e);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error in closing file", e);
                }
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    if (conn.getInputStream() != null)
                        conn.getInputStream().close();
                    if(conn.getErrorStream() != null)
                        conn.getErrorStream().close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error in finally code", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        if (pdRepository != null) {
            String strResult = (String) result;
            if (strResult.startsWith(ERROR)) {
                String strMessage = "Error: " + strResult.substring(ERROR.length()) + ". Try again by pressing menu button and choose Refresh";
                Toast.makeText(DownloadBible.this, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                languageList.clear();
                for (String lang : languageSet) {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("languageName", lang);
                    languageList.add(map);
                }
                languageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnLanguage);
                spinner.setSelection(0);
                if (!refreshBibleList(spinner, 0)) {
                    String strMessage = "Error refreshing bible list. Try again by pressing menu button and choose Refresh";
                    Toast.makeText(DownloadBible.this, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            pdRepository.dismiss();
            pdRepository = null;
        }
    }
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object> {        
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg) {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        StringBuffer destFileName = new StringBuffer(sdcard.getPath());
        destFileName.append(Constants.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER).append("/").append(downloadFileName.toLowerCase()).append(".zip");
        StringBuffer extractedFileName = new StringBuffer(sdcard.getPath());
        extractedFileName.append(Constants.BIBLE_FOLDER).append("/");
        String crc32FileName = destFileName.toString().replaceAll(".zip", ".crc32");
        File destFile = new File(destFileName.toString());

        URL url = (URL) arg[0];
        URL urlCrc32 = (URL) arg[1];
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        InputStream stream = null; //to read
        FileOutputStream out = null; //to write
        InputStream isCrc32 = null;
        double fileSize = 0;
        double downloaded = 0; //
        long prevCrc32 = -1;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferOut = null;
        BufferedInputStream isZip = null;
        DataInputStream isSize = null;
        DataOutputStream osSize = null;
        try {
            File fCrc32 = new File(crc32FileName);
            if (fCrc32.exists() && fCrc32.length() == 12) {
                isSize = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fCrc32));
                prevCrc32 = isSize.readLong();
                fileSize = isSize.readInt();
                isSize.close();
            }               

            //read crc32 file on server
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlCrc32.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000);
            conn.connect();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == 404) {
                conn.disconnect();
                return MISSING_CHECKSUM;
            }
            isCrc32 = conn.getInputStream();
            long crc32 = new DataInputStream(isCrc32).readLong();
            isCrc32.close();
            conn.disconnect();

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000);
            if (crc32 != prevCrc32 || !destFile.exists()) {
                conn.connect();                 
                if (conn.getResponseCode() == 404) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                    return MISSING_BIBLE_FILE;
                }
                fileSize = conn.getContentLength();
                Log.d(TAG, "filesize " + fileSize + url.getFile());
                osSize = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fCrc32));
                osSize.writeLong(crc32);
                osSize.writeInt((int)fileSize);
                osSize.flush();
                osSize.close();
                out = new FileOutputStream(destFileName.toString());
            } else {
                downloaded = destFile.length();
                conn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (int)downloaded + "-");
                conn.connect();
                if (conn.getResponseCode() == 416) { // if range is invalid
                    out = new FileOutputStream(destFileName.toString());
                    conn.disconnect();
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000);
                    conn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000);
                    downloaded = 0;
                } else if (conn.getResponseCode() == 404) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                    return MISSING_BIBLE_FILE;
                } else {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(destFileName.toString(), true);
                }
            }

            final int fileSizeKb = (int) (fileSize / 1024) + 1;
            stream = conn.getInputStream();

            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int read = -1;
            int i = 0;
            while ((read = stream.read(buffer))> -1) {
                i++;                    
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);                 
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    out.flush();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(DownloadBible.this, R.string.downloadCancel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                    return CANCEL;
                }
                downloaded += read;
                if (i % 5 == 0) {
                    out.flush();
                    final int downloadedKb = (int) (downloaded / 1024);
                    final int progress = (int) ((downloaded / fileSize) * 100);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(getResources().getString(R.string.downloading));
                            if (fileSizeKb < 2) {
                                sb.append(downloadedKb).append(" KB");  
                            } else {
                                sb.append(" ").append(progress).append("%\n").append(downloadedKb).append(" / ").append(fileSizeKb).append(" KB");
                            }

                            pdDownload.setMessage(sb.toString());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            //validate checksum
            isCrc32 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(destFile));
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
            while ((len = isCrc32.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                checksum.update(bytes, 0, len);
            }
            isCrc32.close();
            if (checksum.getValue() != crc32) {
                return FILE_CORRUPT;
            }

            //extract file
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(destFileName.toString());
            if (zipFile.size() != 1) {
                return INVALID_BIBLE_FILE;
            }
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipFile.entries().nextElement();
            if (!entry.getName().endsWith(".ont")) {
                return INVALID_BIBLE_FILE;
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pdDownload.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.extracting));
                }
            });
            isZip = new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));
            byte[] bufferExtract = new byte[8192];
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(extractedFileName.toString() + entry.getName().toLowerCase());
            bufferOut = new BufferedOutputStream(outStream, bufferExtract.length);
            int size = -1;
            while((size = isZip.read(bufferExtract, 0, bufferExtract.length)) != -1) {
                bufferOut.write(bufferExtract, 0, size);
            }

            bufferOut.flush();
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (Exception e) {             
            Log.d(TAG, "error in reading/extract file", e);
            return ERROR + Util.getRootCause(e);
        } finally {
            if (isCrc32 != null) {
                try {
                    isCrc32.close();
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error in closing file", ie);
                }
            }
            if (isSize != null) {
                try {
                    isSize.close();
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error in closing file", ie);
                }
            }
            if (osSize != null) {
                try {
                    osSize.close();
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error in closing file", ie);
                }
            }
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error in closing file", ie);
                }
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    if (conn.getInputStream() != null)
                        conn.getInputStream().close();
                    if(conn.getErrorStream() != null)
                        conn.getErrorStream().close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error in closing connection", e);
                }
            }
            if (isZip != null) {
                try {
                    isZip.close();
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error in closing file", ie);
                }
            }
            if (bufferOut != null) {
                try {
                    bufferOut.close();
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error in closing file", ie);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        if (result == null) {
            Toast.makeText(DownloadBible.this, R.string.downloadCancel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        String strResult = (String) result;

        if (pdDownload != null) {                
            pdDownload.dismiss();
            pdDownload = null;
        }
        if (result.equals(SUCCESS)) {
            finish();
        } else if (result.equals(INVALID_BIBLE_FILE)) {
            Toast.makeText(DownloadBible.this, R.string.bibleFileNotValid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (strResult.startsWith(ERROR)) {
            String strMessage = "Error: " + strResult.substring(ERROR.length());
            Toast.makeText(DownloadBible.this, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result.equals(FILE_CORRUPT)) {
            Toast.makeText(DownloadBible.this, R.string.fileCorrupt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result.equals(MISSING_CHECKSUM)) {
            Toast.makeText(DownloadBible.this, R.string.missingChecksum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result.equals(MISSING_BIBLE_FILE)) {
            Toast.makeText(DownloadBible.this, R.string.missingBibleFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    DisplayDownload download = bibleList.get(position);
    downloadFileName = download.getFileName();

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.sdcardNotReady, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return;
    }

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    StringBuffer destFileName = new StringBuffer(sdcard.getPath());
    destFileName.append(Constants.BIBLE_FOLDER).append("/").append(downloadFileName.toLowerCase()).append(".ont");
    File f = new File(destFileName.toString());
    String str;
    if (f.exists()) {
        str = getResources().getString(R.string.confirmDownloadOverwrite);
    } else {
        str = getResources().getString(R.string.confirmDownloadQuestion);
    }
    String confirmQuestion = String.format(str, download.getName());

    confirmDownload.setMessage(confirmQuestion);
    confirmDownload.show();
}

private DownloadTask downloadTask;

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int buttonId) {
    if (dlg.equals(confirmDownload)) {
        if (buttonId == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
            try {
                String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.sdcardNotReady, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    return;
                }
                URL url = new URL(homeUrl + downloadFileName.toLowerCase() + ".zip");
                URL urlCrc32 = new URL(homeUrl + downloadFileName.toLowerCase() + ".crc32");
                Log.d(TAG, "Downloading file: " + url.getPath());
                pdDownload = ProgressDialog.show(this, 
                        getResources().getString(R.string.pleaseWait), 
                        getResources().getString(R.string.downloading), true, true, this);
                downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
                downloadTask.execute(url, urlCrc32);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.downloadUrlNotValid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dlg) {
    if (dlg == pdDownload) {
        downloadTask.cancel(true);
    }

}

private final int menuRefresh = 1;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, menuRefresh, Menu.NONE, R.string.refresh);
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_refresh);
    item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.help, Menu.NONE, R.string.help);
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_help);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case menuRefresh:
        try {
            URL url = new URL(homeUrl + "bible_index_all.txt");
            Log.d(TAG, "Accessing Bible Repository All");
            pdRepository = ProgressDialog.show(this, 
                    getResources().getString(R.string.pleaseWait), 
                    getResources().getString(R.string.loading), true, false);
            new LoadingRepositoryTask().execute(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.repositoryUrlNotValid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        Intent iHelp = new Intent(this, Help.class);
        iHelp.putExtra(Constants.FONT_SIZE, currentFontSize);
        iHelp.putExtra(Constants.HELP_CONTENT, R.string.help_downloadBible);
        startActivity(iHelp);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` That is not SD card. That is external storage. You have already what you want. Go take a break.

Comment: Thanks but this what it shows on android 3.0+   "error open failed enoent (no such file or directory)" i dont know what this actually means

Comment: Indeed with old android versions it can be the sd card..